# Why final methods in java are invoked using invokevirtual opcode

Tags: java

Final methods in java cannot be overridden by the inherited class.

But why the final methods are invoked using `invokevirtual` instead of `invokespecial`.

Comment: from the above link **When you invoke main() in Subclass as defined above, it must print "Superclass's interesting method**, why not invoke the interesting method on object instance type.

Comment: Well, for starters, the class could be recompiled without `final` without recompiling the class that calls the method...

Comment: final is a keyword enforced by the compiler; it has no influence on the generated bytecode https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704024/how-can-one-tell-if-a-local-variable-is-final-from-java-bytecode-related-to

Comment: @LouisWasserman That's precisely what IncompatibleClassChangeError is for. Same applies to static modifier.

Comment: @JulianDurchholz - Incorrect.  *"Changing a class that is declared `final` to no longer be declared `final` **does not break compatibility** with pre-existing binaries. "* - [JLS 13.4.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2Fspecs%2Fjls%2Fse7%2Fhtml%2F%2F/jls-13.html#jls-13.4.2)

Comment: @StephenC You're right (although 13.4.17 applies), but we're already talking about a hypothetical specification in which a final method could legally be invoked as special.

Comment: yea ... i used the wrong reference.  will fix later

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The semantics of the `final` modifier are only enforced by the bytecode **compiler**.

[The link to JavaSE7 specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html)
[Some other samples about `final` keyword.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30151295/variable-final-modifier-lost-in-bytecode)

> The difference between the invokespecial and the invokevirtual instructions is that invokevirtual invokes a method based on the class of the object. The invokespecial instruction is used to invoke instance initialization methods as well as private methods and methods of a superclass of the current class.

When we invoke a final method, corresponding bytecode instruction is `INVOKEVIRTUAL`, the same as other non-final method.

### Here is a example of invoking method with `final` keyword.

CounterPoint.java

```
public class CounterPoint extends Point {

    private static final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();

    public CounterPoint(int x, int y) {
        super(x, y);
        counter.incrementAndGet();
    }

    public static String numberCreated() {
        return counter.toString();
    }

}
```

ByteCode of CounterPoint

```
// class version 52.0 (52)
// access flags 0x21
public class com/xetrasu/CounterPoint extends java/awt/Point  {

  // compiled from: CounterPoint.java

  // access flags 0x1A
  private final static Ljava/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger; counter

  // access flags 0x1
  public <init>(II)V
   L0
    LINENUMBER 11 L0
    ALOAD 0
    ILOAD 1
    ILOAD 2
    INVOKESPECIAL java/awt/Point.<init> (II)V
   L1
    LINENUMBER 12 L1
    GETSTATIC com/xetrasu/CounterPoint.counter : Ljava/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger;
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.incrementAndGet ()I
    POP
   L2
    LINENUMBER 13 L2
    RETURN
   L3
    LOCALVARIABLE this Lcom/xetrasu/CounterPoint; L0 L3 0
    LOCALVARIABLE x I L0 L3 1
    LOCALVARIABLE y I L0 L3 2
    MAXSTACK = 3
    MAXLOCALS = 3

  // access flags 0x9
  public static numberCreated()Ljava/lang/String;
   L0
    LINENUMBER 16 L0
    GETSTATIC com/xetrasu/CounterPoint.counter : Ljava/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger;
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.toString ()Ljava/lang/String;
    ARETURN
    MAXSTACK = 1
    MAXLOCALS = 0

  // access flags 0x8
  static <clinit>()V
   L0
    LINENUMBER 8 L0
    NEW java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger
    DUP
    INVOKESPECIAL java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.<init> ()V
    PUTSTATIC com/xetrasu/CounterPoint.counter : Ljava/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger;
    RETURN
    MAXSTACK = 2
    MAXLOCALS = 0
}
```

AtomicInteger.java

```
public class AtomicInteger extends Number implements java.io.Serializable {
    public String toString() {
        return Integer.toString(get());
    }
    public final int incrementAndGet() {
        return unsafe.getAndAddInt(this, valueOffset, 1) + 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like what you're actually asking is:

> Why would we need a *vtable* lookup for a method that could be linked
> statically?

And rest assured, in practice this lookup is optimized away during linkage - [at least in HotSpot](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/jdk-18+37/src/hotspot/share/oops/cpCache.cpp#L211).

The fact final instance methods are treated as *virtual* rather than *special* seems like a technicality of the JVMS.

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to use `INVOKEVIRTUAL` to call a `final` method in order to implement the binary compatibility rule in [JLS 13.4.17](https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2Fspecs%2Fjls%2Fse7%2Fhtml%2F%2F/jls-13.html#jls-13.4.17).

> "Changing a method that is declared `final` to no longer be declared `final` does not break compatibility with pre-existing binaries. "

If calls to `final` method were compiled to `INVOKESPECIAL`, then those calls would **need** to be recompiled if the method was changed to not be `final`.  That violates the rule above.

But as the other answers / comments have already noted, the JIT compiler will choose the best calling sequence anyway.  Even if you don't declare a method as `final`, the JIT compiler can figure out when no vtable dispatching is necessary.  (And it can even recompile methods when a new class is loaded that invalidates the preconditions.)

Comment: It's worth keeping in mind that other JVM languages might not impose this constraint. But JVMS already forbids `invokespecial` from crossing the class hierarchy, so you couldn't target final instance methods in the general case anyway.